# How can I assign a zenity function to a variable and print what user clicked?

Tags: variables, echo, zenity

I am just testing out some functions in zenity and have hit a little problem.

I want to be able to assign what the user enters when I run `zenity -question` to a variable but when I do I can't echo what the user entered.

The code that I am using is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ans=$(zenity --question --title="Confirm" --text="Please choose yes or no.")

echo $ans
```

On other forums, people suggested this:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --title="Confirm" --text="Please choose yes or no."

echo $?
```

This works, but I know that `$?` just contains the exit status for the most recently run command. I want to be able to save what the user enters to a variable so I can use the answer later on in the script even if I have run something that has over written the answer of `$?`.

My problem is that with my code nothing is returned when I echo the variable.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The exit status contains the answer:

- 0 = YES
- 1 = NO (or dialogue window closed)
- 5 = timeout

### Example

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --timeout=3 --title="Confirm" --text="Please choose YES or NO within 3 seconds."
answer=$?

if [ "$answer" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'YES'
elif [ "$answer" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 'NO'
elif [ "$answer" -eq 5 ]; then
    echo 'timeout'
fi

exit 0
```